# The button showing up on the embed works, but when I click on the button, it says interaction failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

The thing that sends the embed with the buttons

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix+ 'test')) {
    let first = new disbut.MessageButton().setStyle("blurple").setID("1").setLabel("Confirm") //first button
    let second = new disbut.MessageButton().setStyle("red").setID("2").setLabel("Cancel") //second button
    var buttons = [first, second]
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
      .setTitle(":fire: Test")
      .setDescription("Yes")
      .setColor("#BEBDBD")
      .setTimestamp("Today"+ message.createdAt)
      message.channel.send({ embed: embed, buttons: buttons })
```

what will happen when we click on the button

```
     client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
      if (button.id == "1") {
        button.message.channel.send("it worked");
      }
      if (button.id == '2') {
        button.edit(embed.footer("canceled"));
      }
     })
  }
```

Comment: Try console.logging under your event to see if it is running, like this: `client.on('clickButton', async button => {console.log('run successfully'})`

Comment: I already tried that, and it didnt work

Comment: That means that the event isn’t emitting.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the two buttons in a row that is provided with the API. Not in a list

```
let row = new MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(button, button2);
```

[https://discord-buttons.js.org/docs/stable/examples/buttons.html#:~:text=%23-,Multiple%20Buttons,-let%20button%20%3D%20new](https://discord-buttons.js.org/docs/stable/examples/buttons.html#:%7E:text=%23-,Multiple%20Buttons,-let%20button%20%3D%20new)